# Using a button to add images and text to webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I’m making a website for a friend and they would like to be able to add images onto the site without me having to manually go in and put them on through my compiler. Can anyone tell me how I would go about putting something like that into my code. I’ve looked everywhere online and can’t find anything!

Comment: this comes with a backend content management system, add people's emails who are allowed to upload images and write posts / content https://wordpress.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, You need to tell us which technologies this site is using (php, django, ruby on rails, or a CMS like wordpress, joomla, etc), don`t forget to follow these guidelines:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Anyways, you question is tagged with javascript, if you're using js in the backend with nodejs there's a **module** which can help you called **"formidable"**

### Install

```
npm install formidable
```

### Include in your application

```
var formidable = require('formidable')
```

#### Step 1: Create an Upload Form

Create a Node.js file that writes an HTML form, with an upload field:

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  res.write('<form action="fileupload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">');
  res.write('<input type="file" name="filetoupload"><br>');
  res.write('<input type="submit">');
  res.write('</form>');
  return res.end();
}).listen(8080);
```

### Step 2: Parse the Uploaded File

Include the Formidable module to be able to parse the uploaded file once it reaches the server.

When the file is uploaded and parsed, it gets placed on a temporary folder on your computer.

```
var http = require('http');
var formidable = require('formidable');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  if (req.url == '/fileupload') {
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
      res.write('File uploaded');
      res.end();
    });
  } else {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.write('<form action="fileupload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">');
    res.write('<input type="file" name="filetoupload"><br>');
    res.write('<input type="submit">');
    res.write('</form>');
    return res.end();
  }
}).listen(8080);
```

### Step 3: Save the File

When a file is successfully uploaded to the server, it is placed on a temporary folder.

The path to this directory can be found in the "files" object, passed as the third argument in the parse() method's callback function.

To move the file to the folder of your choice, use the File System module, and rename the file:

```
var http = require('http');
var formidable = require('formidable');
var fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  if (req.url == '/fileupload') {
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
      var oldpath = files.filetoupload.path;
      var newpath = 'C:/Users/Your Name/' + files.filetoupload.name;
      fs.rename(oldpath, newpath, function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.write('File uploaded and moved!');
        res.end();
      });
 });
  } else {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.write('<form action="fileupload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">');
    res.write('<input type="file" name="filetoupload"><br>');
    res.write('<input type="submit">');
    res.write('</form>');
    return res.end();
  }
}).listen(8080);
```